# fat file, but missing compatible architecture have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64e' error with bcrypt on Mac M1 Pro chip

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko, apple-m1, arm64

I have recently upgraded from a 2017 MBP to a 2021 MBP with the M1 Pro chip.

Since then i've had issue running a Python 2.7 script.

I am using [paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

...
import paramiko
...
```

...and when I run the script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/crmpicco/deploy.py", line 14, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 90, in <module>
    from paramiko.ed25519key import Ed25519Key
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/ed25519key.py", line 17, in <module>
    import bcrypt
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from bcrypt import _bcrypt
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bcrypt/_bcrypt.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bcrypt/_bcrypt.so' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/_bcrypt.so' (no such file)
```

The file definitely exists, as the error says, but i'm unsure how to proceed.

```
locate bcrypt.so
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bcrypt/_bcrypt.so
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I could find for this was an uninstall and re-install of a bunch of Python packages, name bcrypt, cffi, PyNaCl and cryptography.

```
sudo python2.7 -m pip uninstall bcrypt 
python2.7 -m pip install bcrypt --user

sudo python2.7 -m pip uninstall cffi
python2.7 -m pip install cffi --user

sudo python2.7 -m pip uninstall PyNaCl
python2.7 -m pip install PyNaCl==1.4.0 --user

sudo -H python2.7 -m pip uninstall cryptography
python2.7 -m pip install cryptography --user
```

Comment: Not sure why this works, but it resolved for me.